# Trouble opening phpmyadmin login page from the browser

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql, repository, phpmyadmin

I followed [this](https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/) link to install LAMP server on my Ubuntu 16.04 OS. In the steps given, I have skipped the installation of MariaDB (I went with mysql instead). Also, there was an error while installing `libapache2-mod-php7`. The error that I got during installation is

> Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7

Other than this everything went as per the script. Now when I try to open the phpmyadmin page from my browser using

```
http://server-ip-address/phpmyadmin/
```

I gets a page full of codes instead of a GUI window that asks for login credentials. There are no errors in opening the page etc. It just displays the codes on the browser window.

Where am I missing out on?

Screen shot of the error received: -
[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `libapache2-mod-php7.0` for Apache to interpret PHP. This package is crucial for proper processing of the source code. Try again to install it. I've just checked and it is present in the repository. Do this

`sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0`

(The correct package name is: "libapache2-mod-**php7.0**" not "...-php7".)

Then restart Apache.

`service apache2 restart`

Then check the login page.

Comment: I just did that. It shows the same error. I am using proxy server of my institute to access web. Could that be an issue? I am putting the screen shot of the error in my question

Comment: Maybe. But not likely. Try it again after first doing `sudo apt update`.

Comment: Then just check with `apt search libapache2-mod-php7`.

Comment: I executed the command apt search libapache2-mod-php7. It seemed to run successfully. I am posting the screen shot

Comment: Ok, now it's all clear. The command was wrong. The package name is not ...-php7, but ...-php-7.0.